# Parsing XML to extract positioning parameters

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

From the following XML sequence:

```
<filter>
    <effect>
        <name>Crop</name>
        <parameter>
            <parameterid>left</parameterid>
            <value>1</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterid>right</parameterid>
            <value>2</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterid>top</parameterid>
            <value>3</value>
        </parameter>
        <parameter>
            <parameterid>bottom</parameterid>
            <value>4</value>
        </parameter>
    </effect>
</filter>
```

I am trying to extract the values for the positioning parameters:

```
left: 1
right: 2
top: 3
bottom: 4
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/filter/effect">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parameter"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parameter">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="parameterid" />
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will product this output:

```
left: 1
right: 2
top: 3
bottom: 4
```